# Can't call a component inside a page

Tags: visualforce-component

I would like to create a VF page and call a custom component inside it.

`<apex:page controller="MyController">

<apex:form>

<c:mycomponent id="myId" attributeName="{attributevalue}"/>

</apexform>

<apex:page>`

But this returns me: *'c:mycomponent' component cannot be nested within form tags'*

I have tried to without the  and call this page from another one using the  tag, but it doesn't work either.

I read somewhere that is not possible to do what I need, but in the past I was allowed because I have some examples in my old code.

Is there a workaround now?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What API version is your page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to check if `c:mycomponent` contains an `apex:form` tag and remove it.

Forms cannot be nested, and you can't cheat by wrapping it in a component ;-)

- Possible workaround 1: mock out the `apex:form` with a plain vanilla `form` tag
- Possible workaround 2: put component on a page in an `apex:iframe` to get the visual equivalent

Comment: Yes, I have inside a form. I have added the code. And you are right, now it's not able to do it. But I have some old code with API 20.0 that allowed to me to do it. I was wondering if there was a workaround.

Comment: @AgustinaGarcía Can you replace the `apex:form` with just `form`? How about using an `apex:iframe` to give you the cosmetic equivalent without the nesting?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped me to solve some of my issues. But actually my error was that my component had a <apex:form> inside so, I was not able to call it from another <apex:form>.

Comment: N.B. while swapping the `<apex:form>` with `<form>` gets around the compile time error, you'll get a run time error such as `Content cannot be displayed: <apex:selectList> (under <c:myComponent>) must occur between <apex:form></apex:form> tags.`

Comment: N.B. 2 - wrapping the custom component (if it has an apex:form therein) within an `apex:iframe` will not eliminate the compile time error in the OP