# Create a visual force Component with tags that require form to be used in page within form tags

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have run into a dilemma where I have a bunch of VF page markup and code that is to be used on Two different VF pages. I would like to put all of this code, javascript, etc into a component so it is easier to maintain. The problem,

1. Component uses VF components that require them to be children of an `<apex:form>` tag
2. The component will be used on a VF page which has its own `<apex:form>` tags.

   - The location of the component is within a  tag so I cannot break up the main page form tags as the  will not be properly closed and other TDs have components that require them to be a child of a form.

Since a VF component that contains a form tag cannot be placed within form tags I cannot figure out how to do it.

Anyone have any wise advice?

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me in the past. Find here the link that helped me to sort it out. [Previous question answered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/cant-call-a-component-inside-a-page/11843#11843)

But to sum up, you would need to remove the form from the component. Fin in the link a workaround for that.

Comment: instead of answering with a link to the question you should better mark this question as a duplicate