# Visualforce page <apex:include >issue

Tags: visualforce

When I tried to do this with  I got the following error: 
" Error: 'apex:form' component cannot be nested within form tags " 
If I remove form tag from that page,it contains lots of components that can not survive without form.
For instance if I delete the form tag then it is showing the error like 
" Error:  (under ) must occur between  tags. "

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't call a component inside a page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/cant-call-a-component-inside-a-page)

Answer (score 9):

Pages are meant to be standalone. Depending on your specific use, you need to use the appropriate design pattern. For this discussion, Page1 is the parent page, and Page2 is the page to include.

## Content unrelated, no interaction

If the simple goal is to have Page2 appear within Page1, with no interaction, make sure the page include appears outside Page1's form:

```
 <apex:page>
     <apex:include pageName="Page2" />
     <apex:form> ... </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

As a related alternative, make a third page that uses Page1 and Page2:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:include pageName="Page1" />
    <apex:include pageName="Page2" />
</apex:page>
```

If Page2 is the template and Page1 is a specific page, use a composition:

```
 <!-- Page2 -->
 <apex:page>
     <apex:form> ... </apex:form>
     <apex:insert name="body">
 </apex:page>

 <!-- Page1 -->
 <apex:page>
     <apex:composition template="Page2">
         <apex:define name="body">
             <apex:form> ... </apex:form>
         </apex:define>
     </apex:composition>
 </apex:page>
```

Note that these pages don't strictly "talk" to each other. One simply uses the other as a template or part of the page. This is why they require separate forms. You can never nest forms intentionally or unintentionally. However, if the content is related, you want just one form...

## Content related, requires interaction

Once you start talking about reusable code that needs to interact with each other, the usual way to do this is by use of apex:component. Unlike apex:page, components do not require a form to compile form elements, but they will be required to be contained inside a parent form.

```
<apex:component selfClosing="true">
    <apex:attribute name="var" type="String" description="A String" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!var}" />
</apex:component>

<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <c:myComponent var="{!Account.Name}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Update Page" />
    </apex:form>
    The value you entered in the component is "{!Account.Name}".
</apex:page>
```

The component can directly manipulate the parent's data, as shown in this simple example. It can even contain its own controller, and can optionally be permitted to save data (allowDML="true"). This is *usually* what you want for interaction, while apex:include and apex:composition is usually what you want when no interaction is required (e.g. page templates, navigation menus, etc).

Learning when to use apex:include, apex:define, and apex:composition versus apex:component is something that should come with experience. Each has a specific use and works best when used in that way.

Note that it is technically possible to have two pages interact with each other by includes, but this requires that both pages use the same controller and can coordinate their efforts. This uses up a ton of view state, though, and will slow down the page's loading and response time significantly. It's usually far more efficient to use apex:component for reusable components, even if they are standalone. It's perfectly legal for a page to be nothing more than a host for a single component plus a form (as my examples basically show).